Inserting AdSense in Markdown Content
I'm using Astro to make a blog page and I have several posts. I use MDX for the content management. I'd like to insert AdSense units randomly between paragraphs throughout the content. How to to this?
// blog/[slug].astro

<article>
  <!-- This is where the markdown rendered -->
  <Content/>
</article>



In MDX you can add components to your Markdown.
So write a component AdsenseUnit1.jsx and use it your post1.mdx file.
import AdsenseUnit1 from '../components/AdsenseUnit1.jsx';

---
#example post

some Text

<AdsenseUnit1 />

other Text

See this example: https://github.com/withastro/astro/tree/latest/examples/with-mdx
For the random part: You would probably need to write a component that returns the text and the component randomly placed.
Or let the Adsense script take over the placement of the Ads.
